# Спам или не спам?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Получил замечание за проставленную тревогу на [данном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1235792/seo-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переознакомился со списком стандартных тревог, среди которых в п.5 - Спам (например, [реклама](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor))...
Если это не реклама, не поисковый спам и не размещение внешних ссылок на сторонних (еще и не тематических) ресурсах, тогда что это? Как мне нужно было отреагировать на... это?

PS Сейчас вопрос закрыт под предлогом "На этот вопрос невозможно дать объективный ответ".

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что это спам?

Comment: @Grundy Ссылочный спам — ссылки, «накручивающие» параметр «link popularity» и PageRank сайта, вот: [Поисковый спам](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC)

Comment: Таким макаром можно закрыть **любой** вопрос в котором есть любая ссылка не на so. Плюс, неизвестно насколько важны сейчас указанные тобой параметры для поисковых систем, если даже они и были важны когда-то давно

Comment: Stack Overflow проставляет nofollow в ссылках, так что «ссылочный спам» здесь всё равно бессмысленнен

Comment: Но здесь не одна "ссылка не на so", их три...

Comment: @andreymal это ок, но вопрос немного в другом: какой вид тревоги подходит для этого случая?

Comment: @Jack_oS, конкретный вид тревоги нужно определять в каждом конкретном случае

Comment: Поисковой оптимизацией занимаюсь уже много лет, и по мне так этот вопрос как минимум странный, метка seo явно здесь лишняя)) Спам это, причем откровенный

Comment: [_shrug_](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56859071). Сложно определить.

Comment: на спам уж очень похоже: 1. приведена ссылка на сайт, притом что эта ссылка по смыслу вопроса вообще не нужна. 2. приведены ещё две ссылки на тот же самый сайт, которые ещё менее нужны по смыслу вопроса.

Comment: А сейчас ссылок в вопросе стало меньше

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В таком виде в каком вопрос есть невозможно сказать спам это или нет *точно*. Хотя конечно очень похоже.

Я его [просканировал](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56859071), [проверил](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56859081) сайт на наличие в черном списке/в списке отслеживаемых ключевых слов — ничего не обнаружено. Я [добавил](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56859116) сайт в список временно отслеживаемых ключевых слов (жду пока поаппрувят) — выясним.

Кстати не надо помечать пост как спам, если не уверен. ;)

> Если это не реклама, не поисковый спам и не размещение внешних ссылок на сторонних (еще и не тематических) ресурсах, тогда что это?

Неизвестно реклама это или нет. Размещение ссылок на сторонние ресурсы — это окей, если они не спам.  Что иногда сложно определить.

> Как мне нужно было отреагировать на... это?

Как вариант поставить кастомную тревогу с просьбой разобраться. А можно спросить [здесь](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq).

## UPD

Как выяснилось вопрос является спамом. Были пойманы еще два похожих вопроса: [1](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/posts/uid/ru.stackoverflow/1235792), [2](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/288164). Автор добавлен в черный список, веб сайт из тела сообщения отслеживается.

Comment: "не надо помечать пост как спам, если не уверен"... я и не помечал бы, если б не был уверен )) все-таки закрыли вопрос... что-то выяснили?

Comment: @Jack_oS Как раз только что обновил вопрос ;)

Comment: Вопрос абсолютно точно не является спамом, потому что автор просто был вынужден пересоздать вопрос после его закрытия (один раз, а не два раза). Откуда у вас такие странные логические выводы про спам — непонятно.

Comment: Кроме того, автор собственноручно удалил две лишних ссылки из первого вопроса, что ещё раз подтверждает, что это совершенно не спам. (А из второго вопроса последнюю ссылку удалил уже Kromster, автор её восстанавливать на данный момент не стал)

Comment: @andreymal Сейчас спрошу. Да, вы верно это подметили, хотя вот чисто на мой взгляд выглядит очень похоже на спам...